# Anchored VWAP not working when going timeframe up

Tags: pine-script

My AnchorVwap does not stay at the right place when going up 1 timeframe, like native AnchorVwap drawing tool does.

Example: If I plot my AVWAP on the 14/April/2021 at 4am (4 hour chart) if I go to daily chart my AVWAP will move to the 15th, but AVWAP Drawing tool works correctly at 14th.
If I go to the weekly chart, my AVWAP goes to the 19th, but native Drawing tool goes to the week 12th (which is correct).

So my Anchored Vwap is not consistent when looking in higher timeframes.

```
//@version=4
study("My Midas VWAP plus % offset", shorttitle="MY MIDAS", overlay=true)

startBar01 = input(timestamp('14 Apr 2021 04:00 +0000'), '#1 Start Time', type=input.time)

startmidas01 = time >= startBar01 and time[1] < startBar01

v01 = na(volume) ? 1 : volume
cumV01= cum(v01)
CumPV01= cum(hl2*v01)

startV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,cumV01[1],0)
StartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,CumPV01[1],0)

Midas01 = (CumPV01-StartPV01)/(cumV01-startV01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing that because of the 4am part of your time stamp. Bar timestamps are the opening time of the bar.

On 1D the bar's timestamp would be "14 Apr 2021 00:00 +0000".
Which is less than your input timestamp.
The first bar that is "greater than or equal to" is the 15th.

The same goes for weekly bars. Your timestamp is in the middle of the week. The first weekly bar that is greater than or equal to your input timestamp is the 19th. The previous weekly bar's timestamp is the 12th.

For those higher timeframes, if you are trying to start the VWAP on the bar that contains the timestamp you could do it this way :

```
bool startmidas01 = na

if timeframe.isintraday
    startmidas01 := time >= startBar01 and time[1] < startBar01
else if timeframe.isdwm
    startmidas01 := time <= startBar01 and time_close(timeframe.period) > startBar01
```